# Soundcloud API order on playlist

Tags: api, soundcloud

soundcloud api again!

I'm trying to order the tracks when grabbing a playlist from soundcloud api using this call

http://api.soundcloud.com/users/radio-pnr/playlists/10599585.json?client_id=XXXX

I can limit the tracks by using

> &limit=10

but when I put the

> order=created_at

to return the tracks ordered, this parameters seems to be ignored.
Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Please if my answer helped check it as a valid solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order filter doesn't work anymore, when you retrieve the tracks from a certain user the order filter is set by default to created_at.

Comment: This is correct, the API doesn't support an `order` parameter.