# Javascript search filter created_at still not working?

Tags: javascript, search, soundcloud

I believe this is a known issue, but just checking... when using javascript and sc.get to do a search, the created_at search filter seems to be completely ignored. Tried it using just a 'from' hash, as well as used both 'from' and 'to' hashes to the created_to variable... nada. I get ALL music regardless of date. I'm using the correct syntax as well. ie: 2018-01-01 00:00:00. Other filters in the call seem to work fine. Not sure if this is a problem with the client side or on your server that the request is being made of just not being able to parse it. I'm going to try including this filter using CURL and see if it works there, but I sure would like it to work in my javascript call instead.

relevant code (other filters are used but have been stripped out to simplify the testing of this):

```
var qcreated='2018-01-01 00:00:00'; 

SC.get('/tracks', { created_at: { from: qcreated } }, function (tracks) { ...rest of code here... }
```

the rest of the code bit is extensive and parses and sorts the results. unfortunately the query seems to ignore the created_at filter and I get back songs of all manner of date regardless of what I hard code in.

Comment: we dont know what you have done and what is the problem until unless you provide code that shows your efforts

Comment: var qcreated='2018-01-01 00:00:00'; SC.get('/tracks', { created_at: { from: qcreated } }, function (tracks) { ...rest of code here... }

Comment: please see how to ask a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i use other filters as well, i just simplified this line. THe rest of my code is extensive as it parses and sorts the incoming results. The incoming results unfortunately are all manner of dates, not the ones specified by the filter

Comment: If neede, you can view the complete source code and test it for yourself at http://www.retroresource.com/tezla just press the FIND MUSIC button and it will bring up the music and their attributes based on your search criteria. Created date field is prepopulated but can be changed for testing. Change it and press FIND MUSIC. You'll see that generally none of the results are that date or after

Comment: What is `SC.get()`? IS this part of some framework or library?

Comment: Ahh, it's the SoundCloud API.

Comment: Looks like this may be a known bug in the SoundCloud API. Someone else reported the same problem 2 years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610013/soundcloud-created-atfrom-and-created-atto-not-returning-expected-results

Comment: Yes I read that which is why I thought it was a known issue. Sad to see it still is... HOWEVER, I have figured it out. You can't use both the created_at and genre filters. They will conflict in priority and ONLY the genre filter will spawn results and the created_at will be ignored. If you LEAVE OUT genre filtering, the created_at WILL work. The only way both will work at the same time is is use created_at: last_year instead of from: For some reason this works, but is limiting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Soundcloud API order on playlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622109/soundcloud-api-order-on-playlist)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#get), `SC.get()` returns a promise, it doesn't take the callback as an argument. So it should be:

```
SC.get("/tracks", { created_at: { from: qcreated } }).then(function (tracks) {
    // rest of code here
});
```

This is for version 3 of the SoundCloud SDK -- your method of calling is appropriate for Version 1.

Comment: You're using version 1.1.5 of the SDK, the documentation I found is for version 3.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's help, but I have figured it out. You can't use both the created_at and genre filters. There is still a bug in the API which will conflict in priority and ONLY the genres: filter will spawn results and the created_at will be ignored. If you LEAVE OUT genres: filter, the created_at WILL work. The only way both will work at the same time is by use created_at: last_year instead of from: For some reason this works, but is limited to just the last years worth of uploads.